# Leetcode problem 8 (atoi). Why is my solution so slow?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

This is my solution to [Leetcode problem 8](https://leetcode.com/problems/string-to-integer-atoi/), the `atoi` problem, in Python 3.

This is just a generic `atoi` routine that converts any string into an integer. Front leading whitespaces are ignored, and there can be a sign '+' or '-' in front. 0x30-0x39 in ASCII are digits so subtracting 0x30 gets the digit. Consecutively multiplying by 10 and adding the digit 'extracts' the integer from the string.

```py
class Solution:
    def myAtoi(self, s: str) -> int:
        strt, ans = 0, 0
        s_len = len(s)
        sgn = 1

        # Advance past all the white-space
        while strt < s_len:
            if s[strt] != ' ':
                break
            strt += 1
        else:
            return 0

        # Advance past the sign
        if s[strt] is '-':
            sgn = -1
            strt += 1
        elif s[strt] is '+':
            strt += 1

        # Put the digit in correct dec. place.
        i = strt
        while i < s_len and s[i].isdigit():
            ans *= 10
            ans += ord(s[i]) - 0x30
            i += 1
        return max(min(ans * sgn, 0x7FFFFFFF), -0x80000000)  # Clamp to range [-2^31, 2^31 - 1]
```

I feel like this is a reasonably good solution - nothing stands out as being particularly wrong with it at all. **Except!** That after profiling the code about 20 times I keep getting terrible performance:

[image: Why is this running so slow???]

What gives? I know Leetcode isn't reliable for testing performance so usually I just take the maximum scores but it just isn't budging. So why does it run so slowly?

*EDIT 1:*
As per the suggestion of Aghast and Mast, I changed the code to the following which is more Pythonic:

```py
class Solution:
    def myAtoi(self, s: str) -> int:
        s = list(s)
        strt, ans = 0, 0
        s_len = len(s)
        sgn = 1

        # Advance past all the white-space
        for i, ch in enumerate(s):
            if ch != ' ':
                break
        else:
            return 0

        # Advance past the sign
        if s[i] is '-':
            sgn = -1
            i += 1
        elif s[i] is '+':
            i += 1

        for ch in s[i:]:
            if ch.isdigit():
                # Put the number in correct dec. place.
                ans *= 10
                ans += ord(ch) - 0x30
            else: 
                break
        return max(min(ans * sgn, 0x7FFFFFFF), -0x80000000)  # Clamp to range [-2^31, 2^31 - 1]
```

I actually feel that this is an interesting case study - when just using the `enumerate` OR `list` approach (one or the other) the code ran as slow as before. It is only when I combined both approaches that my code started running faster than 90% of other solutions. Super super weird! If anyone could explain this phenomenon that would help me a lot.

Comment: Because you're writing Python as if you're writing C. Can you shortly phrase the goal of the challenge in your question so people can understand what you're doing without having to find pages outside of the SE network?

Comment: In the question, please. Not in comments. Preferably with testcases.

Comment: Also, its sort of intrinsically hard to NOT have a c-like approach to this problem seeing as its sort of primitive. Even so, suppose I did something like a bunch of casting or took a highly functional approach - I'm likely to do multiple passes over the solution which is technically less efficient (takes a constant multiple of O(n)).

Comment: Python does have a lot of inbuilt functionality of what you're trying to do, so if you come from a C-style mentality before learning Python it does take some getting used to. Don't worry, I had the same problems years ago and it's possible to overcome this :-)

Comment: Yeah true and thanks. What's the actual intuition, then, behind why it is slower? I suppose I could see what it's being compiled into. But let's say, using abstraction as a convenience, that the pythonic way of doing something is faster. Like for instance, why does doing string.replace(thing 1).replace(thing 2) (which presumably compiles to multiple passes over the string) typically outperform doing like a custom loop approach where you check each thing in a single pass? Can doing that really be considered bad practice?

Comment: One problem you might be having is the string indexing. Python has totally embraced unicode strings and defaults to using UTF8. That means that internally, the strings are composed of variable-width characters, even if the particular characters you are using aren't variable width. So you might be doing `str[i]` in code, but Python is doing "search from the beginning of the string for the i'th position" over and over again. Try either explicitly converting the string to a list of single chars, or rewriting to use iteration over the string.

Comment: I think you can do `s = list(s)` to expand a string into a list-of-chars. You ought to then be able to use `s` as normal - same length, same values, etc. So try doing that at the top of your existing code and see what happens to the speed. Otherwise, try rewriting with iteration. `for i, ch in enumerate(s):`

Comment: @aghast It's even easier, I'm writing an answer now.

Comment: @aghast See the edited post. Do you guys know why this is (why it runs faster by using enumerate & list?)

Comment: We could, but that gets a bit off-topic since it's no longer reviewing your code. [CodeAcademy has a piece on it](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/512d0a9a6f94964dd20035ab) and [so does Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808384/what-is-the-implementation-detail-for-enumerate). Basically, enumerate is optimized for such purposes by only doing what it has to.

Comment: Damn what a beast. Thanks

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 7):

At the risk of beating a (seemingly simple, but sometimes subtle) dead horse:

Booboo and Mast have adequately covered why the original code is slow and how to speed it up.

The spirit of Mast's original answer - that Python built-ins need to be better utilized - is correct, and gets close to a solution that is fast and nearly correct - but does not strictly adhere to the specification in Leetcode. We cannot assign any blame here because OP never actually provided that specification in the question body.

Some elements of Booboo's various solutions should be preserved. Namely, when implementing a specification it's a great idea to show in granular detail where an implementation maps to its specification, though (1) we needn't religiously write a C-like character-by-character implementation (which hinders performance), and (2) this could go further in making direct quotes to the specification and writing directly-mapped tests. Comments are free.

I won't make any promises about regexes being the fastest option, but I see them as the simplest way to implementing the spec, and they do avoid the need to loop. "In real life" (as real as we can consider this specification), there are several things you'd want to do:

- If this is performance-critical, start with a simple implementation and only switch to a micro-optimized implementation if the initial performance is deemed to be so slow that you can bear the cost of a higher-complexity library.
- Document the solution against the spec.
- Test. Doctests are well-applied here.
- Real life would not use a wrapper class as Leetcode demands, and would just be a plain function.
- In real life, you would probably want to pay any startup costs (such as regular expression compilation) on module load and not within the function. In Leetcode it probably lumps startup cost and function call cost together.

Also note that there is some subtlety around Unicode. The specification effectively guarantees use of the ASCII character subset of Unicode. The `\d` character class in the Python regular expression could accommodate non-ASCII Unicode digits that should presumably also be parsed to integers, but it's a matter of interpretation as to whether these should be supported or not. In my demonstration I apply `(?a)` to match ASCII only.

### Suggested

```py
"""
https://leetcode.com/problems/string-to-integer-atoi/
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288635
"""
import doctest
import re

# Constraints: s consists of English letters (lower-case and upper-case),
# digits (0-9), ' ', '+', '-', and '.'
INT_PAT = re.compile(
    r'''(?xa)  # Verbose, ASCII (due to constraints)
    \ *        # 1. Read in and ignore any leading whitespace
               # Note: Only the space character ' ' is considered a whitespace character.
    (          # Capture the integer
        [+-]?  # 2. Check if next character is '-' or '+'
        \d+    # 3. Read digits, greedy
    )
    '''
    # 3 (implied). Read in next the characters until the next non-digit character
    # or the end of the input is reached. The rest of the string is ignored.
)

# 5. 32-bit signed integer range [-2**31, 2**31 - 1]
INT32_MIN = -(1 << 31)
INT32_MAX = (1 << 31) - 1


def atoi(s: str) -> int:
    r"""
    Parse s to an integer by the specification in
    https://leetcode.com/problems/string-to-integer-atoi/ .

    >>> atoi("42")               # Example 1
    42
    >>> atoi("   -42")           # Example 2
    -42
    >>> atoi("4193 with words")  # Example 3
    4193

    # Supplementary examples not in specification
    >>> atoi('\t42')
    0
    >>> atoi('\U000007c7')  # Nko Digit Seven, whereas int() = 7
    0
    >>> atoi('xx42')
    0
    >>> atoi('xx42xx')
    0
    >>> atoi('42.0')
    42
    >>> atoi('-42.99')
    -42
    >>> atoi('4 2')
    4
    >>> atoi('+4-2')
    4
    >>> atoi('2147483649')
    2147483647
    >>> atoi('-2147483649')
    -2147483648
    """
    match = INT_PAT.match(s)

    # 4. If no digits were read, then the integer is 0.
    if match is None:
        return 0

    '''
    4. Convert these digits into an integer.
        
    By https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int,
    > the string can be preceded by + or - (with no space in between), have leading zeros, be
    > surrounded by whitespace, and have single underscores interspersed between digits.

    We don't match on underscores so those would be rejected and 0 returned.
    '''
    n = int(match.group(1))

    # 5. If the integer is out of the 32-bit signed integer range, then clamp
    n = min(INT32_MAX, max(INT32_MIN, n))

    # 6. Return the integer as the final result.
    return n


if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod()
```

The doctests pass:

[image: PyCharm doctests]

Comment: I don't use ascii mode but instead use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`, which should have the same effect. So please tell me how your solution differs from mine.

Comment: Many ways, but to pick only one: your tests aren't actually tests at all.

Comment: In what sense are they not tests?

Comment: They don't assert anything. They can't interface with a test framework. They cannot fail - they can only print, and it's up to the user to interpret the results with eyeballs. It would be within reason for Leetcode to actually fail your solution on the grounds that it writes to stdout when it shouldn't.

Comment: You are correct if that is by that definition of "tests". I should have called my answer an implementation plus a demo. BTW, my method itself does *not* print anything; only the demo (which I have since changed to me more test-like) does.

Answer (score 6):

Being an interpreted language native Python code will normally run much more slowly than an equivalent C or C++ program (just two examples of a language that is compiled to native machine language). To overcome this many modules/packages in Python's library (and in the `PyPI` repository) are implemented in C, at least in part, such as the `int` function that one normally uses for converting a string to an integer. But if we were to assume that the `int` function did not exist and had to write one in Python following the steps that were specified in the problem description, then your approach is essentially what is required.

The following is how I would solve the problem. My approach is not vastly different than yours, but I think it may be a bit more concise (and Pythonic).

```py
class Solution:
    @staticmethod
    def myAtoi(s: str) -> int:
        s = s.lstrip(' ')  # Ignore leading spaces
        if len(s) == 0:
            return 0  # Empty string

        if s[0] in ('+', '-'):
            # Leading sign?
            sign = s[0]
            s = s[1:]   # Examine rest of the string
        else:
            sign = '+'

        result = 0
        for ch in s:
            # Process next digit
            # Is it valied digit ?
            if ch.isdigit():
                result = result * 10 + ord(ch) -  ord('0')
            else:
                break  # Done scanning
        # Process leading sign:
        if sign == '-':
            result = -result

        # Force range:
        return max(min(result, 2**31 - 1), -(2 ** 31))

# Test function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tests = [
        '  0 ',
        '  123  ',
        '  -123XXX',
        '999999999999999999',
        '-999999999999999999'
    ]

    for test in tests:
        print(repr(test), '->', Solution.myAtoi(test))
```

Prints:

```None
'  0 ' -> 0
'  123  ' -> 123
'  -123XXX' -> -123
'999999999999999999' -> 2147483647
'-999999999999999999' -> -2147483648
```

**A Solution Using Full Facilites of Python**

The following solution uses a regular expression to determine the substring of the input to be converted with the `int` function:

```
^ *([+-]?[0-9]+)
```

1. `^` - Matches the start of the line.
2. `*` - Matches 0 or more leading spaces (note that this is a leading space character followed by '*', which might be difficult to see).
3. `(` - Start of capture group 1.
4. `[+-]` - An optional sign, either '+' or '-'.
5. `[0-9]+` - One or more Ascii digits.
6. `)` - End of capture group 1.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xRKPPz/1).

When the above regular expression is used with the `re.match` method, the regular expression must match characters only at the very start of the input string and therefore the '^' *anchor* is not required and is omitted in the code below.

If there is a match, capture group 1 will contain just the optional sign followed by all subsequent digits (but at least one) up to but not including the first non-digit is encountered or end of string. This non-digit character might be a decimal point, which will not be included in the match. Consequently, input such as '123.45' will be treated as if it were '123'. In other words, the decimal point and any following digits will be ignored, which will not affect the final result. Then it's a simple matter to apply the `int` function to the matched string to convert it to an integer (if the matching is correct there is no chance of that this conversion will raise an exception) and then we ensure the result is within the required boundaries.

```py
class Solution:
    import re

    # Valid input as a regular expression:
    rex = re.compile(r' *([+-]?[0-9]+)')

    @staticmethod
    def myAtoi(s: str) -> int:

        m = Solution.rex.match(s)
        return max(min(int(m[1]), 2**31 - 1), -(2 ** 31)) if m else 0

# Test function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tests = [
        ('  0 ', 0),
        ('\n1', 0),
        ('  123  ', 123),
        ('  -123XXX', -123),
        ('+999999999999999999', 2147483647),
        ('-999999999999999999', -2147483648),
        ('4193 with words', 4193),
        ('123.45', 123)
    ]

    for test, expected_result in tests:
        actual_result = Solution.myAtoi(test)
        if actual_result != expected_result:
            print(f'Result for {repr(test)} was {actual_result} instead of {expected_result}')
```

Comment: I think your fixation on needing to re-write `int()` is frankly a little bizarre. The question doesn't ask for C++; it doesn't even ask for a C++-like answer. It only asks for a _functional contract similar to `atoi` from C++_. Those are vastly different things.

Comment: @Reinderien Am I really the only one that sees explicitly the instructions that says (in part): **1. Read in and ignore any leading whitespace. 2. Check if the next character (if not already at the end of the string) is '-' or '+'. Read this character in if it is either. This determines if the final result is negative or positive respectively. Assume the result is positive if neither is present. 3. Read in next the characters until the next non-digit character or the end of the input is reached. The rest of the string is ignored. 4. Convert these digits into an integer ...**?

Comment: I assure you that I can read. The description you quote is a behavioural description. I'm sure that you're smart enough to recognize that what a function does and how it's implemented can in practice look quite different. Especially in an environment like Leetcode, any implementation that achieves the same behaviour and passes all of the test cases is acceptable, even if it isn't a scriptural word-by-word transliteration of the specification.

Comment: @Reinderien You probably gave me too much credit. But even taking the description as a just a specification for *what* the function must accomplish rather than *how*, the solution posted by Mast does not accomplish that. If the input were 'AAA 123', the function would return 123 instead of the correct value, 0 (see Step 3).

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere! This calls for a solution that's efficient (using `int`) but also meets the specification.

Comment: @Reinderien Do you feel like writing one?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on it :)

Comment: I have added a solution using `int` (and an explanation for the original code's slowness).

Comment: The performance comparison report at LeetCode is comparing with other Python solutions, which have the same interpreter overload. No one is expecting it to be as fast as C or C++>

Answer (score 3):

Why it's slow? Because you found a complicated way to do something simple.

The testcases from Leetcode are:

```
""42""
"   -42"
"4193 with words"
```

Split the string, throw away anything that's whitespace or a not a number and you're done.

Something along the lines of:

```
for section in s.split():
    try:
        answer = int(section)
    # on failure, keep going with other sections
    except:
        continue
    return answer
```

Split on whitespace, iterate over the sections and check each section for an integer. Found one? Return as integer and continue. Making the above fit in a style that Leetcode accepts remains as an exercise.

You're not interested in the length of the string, only in the parts that look like an integer. You don't have to check every character. Simply consider a section as a whole and check that instead.

Python is a language that comes batteries included, so any approach that takes a C-style approach would utterly fail to be fast.

Comment: The problem as I read it was meant for a C++ solution and it provided precise steps for implementing the function. As a Python exercise it does not make much sense. That said, your solution is not in the spirit of the problem because it is taking the short cut of using the built-in `int` function rather than following the steps specified in the problem description. This is akin to a C++ solution using the `atoi` standard library function. If you are not supposed to use `atoi` in your C++ solution, then you shouldn't be using `int` in your Python solution.

Comment: @Booboo Where in the question does it state a C++-like solution was requested?

Comment: @Booboo yeah I totally agree. Still, it is being benchmarked versus other python solutions. I find it weird that the 2nd approach (see the edit) solves the problem.

Comment: @Mast It implies a C++ solution. Just look at the right frame for entering your solution. The language is C++.

Comment: @Booboo Have you tried setting the language to something else? The question is tagged Python, not C++.

Comment: @Mast Again, the major problem I find with your answer is that you did not follow the explicit steps requested to solve the problem. Other people seem to appreciate your solution (their privilege), so be happy. Re-read my comment wherein I said, "That said, ...". I have no problem with a Python solution -- just one that used `int()`.

Comment: @Booboo If a specific approach was intended, it should've been mentioned in the question instead of behind a link. It was not. Just as all code [should be posted in the question itself](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1309), there are no guarantees external links will be taken into consideration. The question was why it was slow and the answer is that the approach is needlessly complicated. The question was why it was slower than other Python contributions and we know nothing about the style used in those. It is your right to disagree with it and post an alternative (as you did).

Comment: @Booboo -- plus a dropdown that has about a dozen other languages to choose from...

Comment: @Gábor i surrender!

Comment: The question is about how to *implement* `atoi()` in Python. You're not really implementing it if you just use the Python equivalent of that function. The point of programming exercises like this it to learn the underlying algorithms, even if you're using a language that provides it as a built-in. Your solution would be OK if the question were about how to ignore the leading whitespace and trailing text around the number, but that's not what "implement atoi" sounds like to me.